# How to dequeue from virtual topic in ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

There are a lot of questions about how to dequeue VirtualTopic in ActiveMQ but all of them are pretty old and still no answered.

I've posted a message to VirtualTopic.exerciser and this message was consumed by queue consumers. Everything works fine on my BE, but AMQ broker UI still displays that message was not dequed from topic. (Please take a look at screenshots).

NB: I do not have topic listener.
[No message was dequeued from VitrualTopic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F9iQ.png)

[Messages were dequeued from VirtualTopic consumer queues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oq9hS.png)

I've tried to find any response workable response on stackoverflow and Active MQ website. I've read doc but there is no answer there for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virtual Topic is simply that a Topic and Topics in JMS do not retain messages unless there is a subscription.  If you have a client subscribed to the Topic the message would be routed to it but if there is no subscription the message is dropped.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tim. So that, if I have consumer queues than I do not have to worry about messages in topic, it won't consume resources. Did I understand you well?

Comment: If a Topic has no consumer the messages are discarded, if you have consumers then they get messages.